# Bash Script to copy n number of files and rename sequentially

Tags: bash, shell, rename, batch-rename

I have a template file that I use to submit PBS jobs to a server. I need to make *n* number of copies of this template. Ultimately I would like to enter the following command or something similar:

```
copy n pbs_template
```

I would like the newly made duplicate files to be named:

```
pbs_template_1
pbs_template_2
pbs_template_3
pbs_template_4
pbs_template_n....
```

The following is what i have so far...

```
function copy() {
    INPUT=pbs_template
    number=$1
    shift

    for n in $(seq $number); do
     cp "$INPUT" "$INPUT"
    done
}
```

Obviously I need to specify the name of my output (otherwise I get the following error `cp: pbs_template and pbs_template are identical (not copied)`), but how do I make them number sequentially *n* times?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this?

```
function duplicate () {
    for i in $(seq 1 $2)
    do
        cp $1 "$1_$i"
        echo "Made copy '$1_$i'"
    done

}
```

You call it like so `duplicate foo.txt 10`. It will create 10 copies of `foo.txt` each with a numerical suffix. In this invocation, `$1` will be `foo.txt` and `$2` will be `10`.

Comment: Maybe take out the obnoxious `echo`, or at least make it print to standard error instead.

Comment: Of course. It's crude documentation to help the OP understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

just change your statement to this,

```
cp -p "$INPUT" "$INPUT"_${n}
```

here i have used `-p` switch in order to preserve attributes of file.
If you don't want then just ignore `-p` switch.

Hope that helps.